# spring data specification query on text column which contains json

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one table like Product and it has column `instance` and its data type is `text`.

Table data is like below and I have written a query to extract data from that instance column.

```
select id, instance, jsonb_extract_path_text(instance::jsonb,'isDefaultRuleForTraffic')as extractedData
    from product where jsonb_extract_path_text(instance::jsonb,'isDefaultRuleForTraffic') = 'true'
```

| id | instance | extractedData |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"isDefaultRuleForTraffic":true,"name":{"name":"test"}} | true |
| 2 | {"isDefaultRuleForTraffic":false,"name":{"name":"test"}} | false |

My question is, How can I write this query in Spring data JPA specification using predicate?

I have tried the below code but it is not working.

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    return builder.equal(builder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class, root.get("instance"),
        builder.literal("isDefaultRuleForTraffic")), "true");
}
```

Any other approach using predicate would be also appreciated?

Comment: Instead of using `CriteriaBuilder` or `CriteriaQuery` have you tried using the standard spring-data query creation from method names (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)? This sounds straightforward case of using `Like` or `Containing` keyword in the method name along with desired parameter value

Comment: I have to use CB or CQ due to common implementation of search mechanism

Comment: `but it is not working`. What error do you get? I also see that in SQL query you perform casting (`instance::jsonb`) and in JPA query you don't, that's might be the reason.